# Power Builder 12.5 - AutoSize Height column in report dw

Tags: powerbuilder

** Updated: I realized when it prints, the said blank row will disappear. Thank you.**

Not sure if you ever encountered the issue below.

I have a column, description in my detail band.
Both description and detail band is set to autosize height.
However, certain description will cause having a blank row after this row as shown in the pic below.

As from the pic, second last description is just enough to be fit into the column, but not sure why it cause extra row after this.
Last description shows that autosize height works well.

FYI, no leading and trailing spacing.
If autosize height is unticked, it won't have extra row after the second last. But it will cause those long description can't be shown in full.

[Report Printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yfi3.png)

Anyone encountered this before?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Autosize height is a nice feature if it worked perfectly but it never has.  Maybe you need a little more horizontal space because that column is not showing both "2" for the year 2022 which is kicking the band into autosize height but the column is not.  I have seen things like this and I usually have to try getting creative with work-arounds, changing column widths, or maybe turning border off and see what that does.

This is not one of my favorite problems to solve along print preview being different for users having different printers (drivers).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried your suggestion before, but it is not the perfect solution. As it might have the same issue when the description is different. I can't find any other solution as for now.